# To open a popup window on clicking link button in grid view control

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview

In the below code i have a grid view inside grid view i have a link button when i click the link button it should open a popup window .pls help me to do this.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvActList" runat="server" Font-Size="Smaller" Width="100%" CssClass="tableStyle"
EmptyDataText="No Data Found" AllowPaging="false"
CellPadding="4" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowDataBound="gvActList_RowDataBound">
<FooterStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="tablefooter" />
<RowStyle CssClass="tableRow1" />
<SelectedRowStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="tableRowHighlight" />
<HeaderStyle Font-Bold="True" CssClass="tableHeader" Font-Size="9px" />
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TM Activity Code" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Activity_Code" runat="server" Visible="true" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_CODE") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Description" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="19%" HorizontalAlign="Left"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_ACTDESC" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_DESC") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User Details" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_User_Details" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CREATED_BY") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_PROMO_TYPE" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PROMO_TYPE") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCatgDescription" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CATEGORY_CODE") %>'
                Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblACTIVEFROM" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE_FROM") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>&#160; To &#160;
            <asp:Label ID="lblACTIVETO" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVE_TO") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Activity Type" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Actvity_Type" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_TYPE") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Current Status" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemStyle Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Current_Status" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' Visible="true"></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="View Details" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <itemstyle width="5%" />
            <asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link" Text="View" ID="lnkView" runat="server" ToolTip="View" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblCap" Text="Confirm" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center"></ItemStyle>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <itemstyle width="1%" font-size="2px" horizontalalign="Center" />
            <table style="text-align: Center; vertical-align: text-top;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 98%;">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" GroupName="CH"></asp:RadioButton></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 98%;">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdNo" runat="server" Text="No" GroupName="CH"></asp:RadioButton></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 98%;">
                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rdNone" runat="server" Text="None" GroupName="CH"></asp:RadioButton></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
<EditRowStyle CssClass="tableRowHighlight" />
<RowStyle CssClass="odd_tb" />
<PagerStyle CssClass="foot_tbl" />
<AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="even_tb" />
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" />
```

.js file is given below

```
function view_Data(v_Act_Code) {
        window.open("viewApprovalDetails.aspx?ACTCODE=" + v_Act_Code, 'ViewChange', 'height=440,width=650,left=150,top=150,screenX=0,screenY=100');
    }
```

How can i open new pop up window by clicking on grid view link button 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In grid view , for Link button, use markup like below

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link" Text="View" ID="lnkView" runat="server" 
ToolTip="View"  OnClientClick='<%#string.Format("return view_Data(\"{0}\");",
  DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ACTIVITY_CODE")) %>' />
```

In javascript, return false from function,so on linkbutton click postback wont occur

```
function view_Data(v_Act_Code) {
  window.open("viewApprovalDetails.aspx?ACTCODE=" + v_Act_Code, 'ViewChange',
'height=440,width=650,left=150,top=150,screenX=0,screenY=100');

return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind javascript click event on `LinkButton`. Pass the `ACTIVITY_CODE` to view_Data javascript function and return `false` if you do not want the PostBack.

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link" Text="View" 
        OnClientClick='view_Data(<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_CODE") %>); return false;'
        ID="lnkView" runat="server" ToolTip="View" />
```

Comment: I included js file inside the <body> it is not showing any eeror but not opening the new window @Adil

Comment: Include js file in head tag and put alert in your js function to check it is getting called, You would be getting error if function is not being called.

Comment: You would get error in browser when you click on link button, this is how you can check in chrome, http://superuser.com/questions/52263/javascript-error-console-in-chrome

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<asp:LinkButton CssClass="l_link" Text="View" ID="lnkView" 
     runat="server" ToolTip="View" 
     OnClientClick='javascript:return view_Data(<%# Bind("ACTIVITY_CODE") %>)' />
```

and in JavaScript

```
function view_Data(v_Act_Code) {
        window.open("viewApprovalDetails.aspx?ACTCODE=" + v_Act_Code, 'ViewChange', 'height=440,width=650,left=150,top=150,screenX=0,screenY=100');
       //return false; if you don't want a postback
    }
```

Comment: Is it giving you any error, set `debuuger;` in your JavaScript function and check whether its being called or not.

Comment: try setting debuuger in your js function like this
`function view_Data(v_Act_Code) {
debugger;
        window.open("viewApprovalDetails.aspx?ACTCODE=" + v_Act_Code, 'ViewChange', 'height=440,width=650,left=150,top=150,screenX=0,screenY=100');
       //return false; if you don't want a postback
    }` and check its being called or not

Comment: i included in head section still it is noc caling new window

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54905/discussion-between-sid-m-and-user123).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-GridView-Row-details-inside-jQuery-Dialog-Modal-Popup-in-ASPNet.aspx 
this link will guide to do so..!!